# Webpack and Web Workers in ionic 2

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, ionic2, web-worker

We are planning to use web workers in an ionic 2 application. However ionic 2 uses ionic-app-scripts (https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-app-scripts, we are using version 1.0.0) with webpack. We need to have a webworker typescript file that is compiled to JS but NOT bundled with the other files as main.js.

What we had in mind was to have a file name format such as

servicetest.worker.ts where the ".worker" file extension part will be identified and compiled from typescript to javascript but not bundled along with the other files.

Any advice on this is much appreciated as it seems that we have to customize the appscripts.

Answer (score 1):

Kind of a really late answer but perhaps it may help someone else.
Take a look at https://www.javascripttuts.com/how-to-use-web-workers-with-ionic-in-one-go/

I followed that article but had to make some adjustments because I had to call a worker method on demand, not on the constructor.

On the `./src/assets` folder create a new folder called workers where your *worker.**JS*** files will live. Yes **JS** not **TS**, as far as I know TypeScript files won't compile to an usable webworker.

Create a webworker. I'll paste the main code of my fuzzySearch webworker (`./assets/workers/fuzzysearch-worker.js`):

```
'use strict';

var pattern, originalList;
self.onmessage = function(event) {
    // Receive a message and answer accordingly
    pattern = event.data.pattern;
    originalList = event.data.originalList;
    self.doFuzzySearch();
};

self.doFuzzySearch = function() {
    var filteredList;

    console.time('internalFastFilter');
    filteredList = self.fastFilter(originalList, (item) => self.hasApproxPattern(item.searchField, pattern));
    console.timeEnd('internalFastFilter');

    // Send the results back 
    postMessage({ filteredList: filteredList });    
};

// The code above is purposely incomplete
```

On your .**ts** file declare the worker variable (usually above the constructor):

```
private readonly searchWorker: Worker = new Worker('./assets/workers/fuzzysearch-worker.js');
```

On the constructor:

```
constructor(/* Other injected dependencies here */
    public ngZone: NgZone) {       

        this.searchWorker.onmessage = (event) => {
          // Inside ngZone for proper ChangeDetection
          this.ngZone.run(()=> {                        
            this.dataList = event.data.filteredList;
            console.timeEnd('searchWorker');
          })
        };        

  }
```

Finally, on your "*action function*", lets say `doSearch`:

```
doSearch(event) {
    // ... extra code to do some magic

    console.time('searchWorker');
    this.searchWorker.postMessage({ command: 'doFuzzySearch', originalList: this.realList, pattern: searchFilter });

    // ... extra code to do some other magic
}
```

`this.searchWorker.postMessage` makes the call. All heavy loading operations are  resolved inside the webworker.

Hope it helps.
Best regards.